# limit users on a lookup for a specific record type?

Tags: force.com

I have a field that's related to users, that's used across record types. Is it possible to limit the users it displays on one of the record types to a certain profile, group, role, etc?

Comment: Are lookup filters available on User? I can't recall.

Comment: do those work on different record types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use lookup filters for this. In order to cope with the recordtypes, add some filter logic, e.g. setup these filters:

1. Userlookup.Profile Name equals 'Profile 1'
2. TheObject.Record Type equals 'RecordType A'
3. Userlookup.Profile Name equals 'Profile 2'
4. TheObject.Record Type equals 'RecordType B'
5. TheObject.Record Type equals 'RecordType C'

with the following filter logic:
(1 AND 2) OR (3 AND (4 OR 5))